# Redirect some url to https in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I want that this url be redirect to https:

```
www.example.com/iscrizioni
www.example.com/inscripciones
www.example.com/inscripcions
```

and all others to http

How I can do it in htaccess?

Regards

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(iscrizioni|inscripciones|inscripcions) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^/?(iscrizioni|inscripciones|inscripcions) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```