# htaccess HTTPS and HTTP query string redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a query with regards to `.htaccess` and redirecting some things.

I currently have a site that requires sitewide HTTPS. This is done via the `.htaccess` file.

I require two things to be on HTTP however: `/sage/` and `/index.php?route=ebay/openbay`.

I currently have the following in place for `sage`, and it works. There is no loop and the redirect works fine.

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.co\.uk$ [NC]
##check if https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
## if so, redirect to http
RewriteRule ^/?(sage) http://www.site.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
## happy days! it works!

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.co.uk$ [NC]
##lets check again but this time for any remaining http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
##if so redirect it back to https, unless sage is at the start.
RewriteRule !^/?(sage) https://www.site.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
##great, still ahve sitewide https except on sage, mission accomplished.
```

Now, I have the problem of the line with the query string.

This is what I have, and it is placed under the above code in the htaccess.

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=ebay/openbay/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !route=ebay/openbay/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NC,QSA]
```

Not only does this work, it creates a redirect loop with this and sage. I'm not sure why and I'm a little stuck.

I originally took the idea from an old post: [Redirect some url to https in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064921/redirect-some-url-to-https-in-htaccess), hoping that I could just add the two strings in the brackets so (`sage/index.php` etc)

I'm at a bit of a loss now, so I think its time to ask the world for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, see if it avoids loop for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sage/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !route=ebay/openbay/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sage/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=ebay/openbay/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: This does indeed solve the loop that was being created, thank you.